# Better to use foreign key or to assign unique ids?

Tags: foreign-keys, relational-database, mariadb

A simplified model of the database is that, say I have a table of `A`, which has columns `a, b, c, d` (so that `(a, b, c, d)` is the primary key). Then I have another table `B` to store some list-like data for each entry in `A`, in order to stay with the first normal form.

This `B` table therefore, will have columns `a, b, c, d, e`, where each `e` entry is one element in the list. It is natural to have a foreign key constraint on `(a, b, c, d)` in `B` which enforces integrity that every thing must exist in `A` first then `B`.

But I wonder if the foreign key constraint will let the database engine to compress or to not duplicate the data storage in B? (In other words, will `(a, b, c, d)` be stored again verbatim and identical to what is in A?) If no, will assigning each entry in `A` a unique ID a better choice in this case?

Comment: In your example there are a number e elements associated to the same (a,b,c,d) element. Each e element is different so there is no duplication in terms of entities. On another side a,b,c,d would be a a natural key for A, you could also determine that A, and B, should have an artiffical id instead, for example a unique integer id. Then a,b,c,d would be represented for example with the unique number 1. and each e elemente, would have a 1 as a foreing key to B. In that way what "travels" to the child table is a 1 instead of (a,b,c,d). I would say which to use depends on context.

Comment: @Juan, thanks for the reply. I think I might have not said it clear enough. What I'm concerned is that if each entry in table `A`, when `B` references it, will be stored again separately, though identical, in B, thus creating data duplication?

Comment: The thing is it is identical in your specific case where the only thing you have is the primary key. In real cases you have more attributes in the entity,  which are not getting duplicated. Think of a Employee table. The key could be his national id, and besides of that name, telephone, deparment, extension, etc that are not part of the pk.

Comment: My current generic comment re "better"/"best" etc: There's no such thing as "better"/"best" in engineering unless *you* define it. Also unfortunately all reasonable practical definitions require a ridiculous amount of experience with a ridiculous number of factors that interact with chaotic sensitivity to details. Make straightforward designs. When you demonstrate via measurement that a design and all alternatives you can think of have problems (whatever that means at the time), then ask a very specific question. Which should also define "better"/"best". https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461

Comment: Why do you even care? What did you learn reading the mentions of FKs, indexes & optimization in the manual? An answer to your question is a chapter on those topics. You could give a [mcve] of an exact case--but see my previous comment re it being worth whatever "cost" you ascribe. PS Lists are ordered. I guess you mean that an A thing has an associated *set*? PS Your questions are duplicates--eg google your title & tags & 'natural key'.

Comment: @philipxy, I defined better to be "costing less storage space", as you can read from my later in my question. But I do want to hear about other factors that may affect choosing between the two. If you feel inappropriate, feel free to edit. Also mcve is more relevant to code/debugging question, which apparently does not apply here.

Comment: You don't define what "better" means, and when used in your title we can guess it means "less space" due to your post body, but it does not clearly mean "less space" in the last sentence's "if no" case, where you could edit in a way that clearly says what you mean. Also, if you want details of what the DBMS does please give exact code--hence a MCVE.

Comment: (Another multi-col PK example:) A basic many:many mapping table has exactly 2 columns, and both are in the PK.  Adding a surrogate `id` as the PK wastes both space and speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most SQL-based database engines do require foreign key values to be physically stored at least twice (in the referencing table and in the parent table). It would be nice to have the option not to do that in the case of large foreign keys. Many database designers will choose to avoid large foreign keys, partly because they have this additional overhead.

Most DBMSs *do* provide the option to compress data - foreign key or not. In many cases that will probably more than compensate for the physical duplication of data due to a foreign key.

Foreign keys are a logical construct however, and in database design it's important to distinguish between logical and physical concerns.

Answer (score 1):

**Table Storage:** Each MySQL table is stored completely separately.  In some cases, two table may live in the same OS file, but the blocks (16KB for InnoDB) will be totally separate.  Therefore, (a,b,c,d) shows up in at least 2 places in the dataset -- once in A and once in B.

A **`FOREIGN KEY`** has the side effect of creating an extra `INDEX` is there is not one already there.  (In your case, you said it was the PK, so it is already an index.)  Note that an FK does not need a `UNIQUE` index.  (In your case, the PK is unique, but that seems irrelevant.)

A ***secondary* index** (as opposed to the `PRIMARY KEY`) for a table is stored in a separate BTree, ordered by the key column(s).  So, if (a,b,c,d) had not already been indexed, the FK would lead to an extra copy of (a,b,c,d), namely in the secondary index.

There is one form of **compression** in InnoDB:  You can declare a table to be `ROW_FOMAT=COMPRESSED`.  But this has nothing to do with de-duplicating (a,b,c,d).

**Four columns** is a lot for a PK, but it is OK.  If it is 4 `SMALLINT` values, then it is only 8 bytes (plus overhead) per row per copy of the PK.  If it is a bunch of `VARCHARs`, then it could be much bulkier.

When should you deliberately **add a surrogate `id`** as the PK?  In my experience, only about one-third of the cases.  (Others will argue.)  If you don't have any secondary keys, nor FKs referencing it, then the surrogate is a waste of space and speed.  If you have only one secondary key or FK, then the required space is about the same.  This last situation is what you described so far.

**Table size:** If you have a thousand rows, space is not likely to be an issue.  A million rows might trigger thinking more seriously about space.  For a billion rows, 'pull out all stops'.

PK **tips**:  Don't include `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, someday there will need to be two rows with the same second.  Don't put more columns in the PK than are needed for the implicit uniqueness constraint; if you do, you effectively lose that constraint.  (There are exceptions.)